# How do I make this Javascript function open the site in a new tab?

Tags: javascript, html

How do I make this function open the link in a new tab?
I read somewhere that I should use an anchor element instead of using JS to open the link.

```
<h1 onclick="randomSite();">Click<br>Me</h1>
            <script>
    var sites = [
        'www.google.com',
        'www.youtube.com',
        'www.facebook.com',
        'www.stackoverflow.com'
    ];

    function randomSite() {
        var i = parseInt(Math.random() * sites.length);
        location.href = sites[i];
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

replace `location.href` with `window.open`, and utilize `'_blank'` like below:

```
window.open(sites[i],'_blank');
```

Comment: @Tim Mcpherson did I answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

```
<h1 onclick="randomSite();">Click<br>Me</h1>
            <script>
    var sites = [
        'http://www.google.com',
        'http://www.youtube.com',
        'http://www.facebook.com',
        'http://www.stackoverflow.com'
    ];

    function randomSite() {
        var i = parseInt(Math.random() * sites.length);
      window.open(sites[i], '_blank');
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple structure such as this can be set to execute this

````
  
<body> 

    <p>Click the button to open a new tab </p> 

  

    <button onclick="NewTab()"> 

      Open Google

  </button>


   <script> 

        function NewTab() { 

            window.open(     "https://www.google.org", "_blank");

      } 

    </script> 
</body> 

</html> ```
````

Answer (score 0):

In your `randomSite()` function exchange `location.href = sites[i];`
with:

`window.open('http://' + sites[i],'_blank');`

Perhaps you can use the location.href command somehow, I'm not familiar with it. Opening a window is straight forward though and if you add the attribute '_blank' it opens in new tab.

Answer (score -1):

Create a new `HTMLAnchorElement` and use its `click` method (not the `click` event):

```
function onHeadingClicked( e ) {
    
    const a = document.createElement( 'a' );
    a.target = '_blank';
    a.href   = getRandomUrl();
    a.click();
}
```

```
<h1 onclick="onHeadingClicked(event)">Click me</h1>
```

Comment: The `click()` method just triggers the `click` event. It's the `target` that matters.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Correct, but browser support for directly raising DOM events is spotty if you need to support legacy browsers which is why I prefer using `.click()` instead of `dispatchEvent`. Also, in the OP's code there isn't an extant `<a>` element (as they're using the `<h1>` and a random URI). My also approach avoids browsers sometimes blocking or intercepting `window.open` too:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open#Browser_compatibility

Comment: My point is that you don't need to trigger the event at all. With a simple `click` handler, you just need to run `window.open(url, _blank);` and you're done.